# Difference between values and Value in Scala Enumeration

Tags: scala, enumeration

I am new to Scala.  Please help me understand the difference between values and Value in the below code:

```
 object CardsEnum extends Enumeration{

type CardsEnum = Value
val spades = Value("♠")
val diamonds = Value("♦")
val hearts = Value("♥")
val clubs = Value("♣")
def isRed(c:CardsEnum.Value) = c==hearts || c==diamonds
}

object NewCardsEnum extends App{
import CardsEnum._

CardsEnum.values foreach println

println(for (e <- CardsEnum.values) yield (e,isRed(e)))

}
```

Comment: There is a type Value, a method Value to create them, and a method values to collect them. But everyone will say don't bother to sort through that as a new user. There are questions about why not to use Scala's old Enumeration.

Answer (score 3):

This is just a type alias:

```
type CardsEnum = Value
```

It is not mandatory, it simply always you to use `CardsEnum` as a type:

```
import CardsEnum._

def func(e: CardsEnum) = ...
```

Instead of having to write `CardsEnum.Value`:

```
def func(e: CardsEnum.Value) = ...
```

This line declares a new variable named `spades` with the result of invoking the method `Value`:

```
val spades = Value("♠")
```

The method `Value("♠")` creates a new object with name `("♠")` and adds it to your enumeration. The name you provided as an argument is used by the `toString` method.

All the values added to your enumeration are in the `.values` collection, which means that this will print `♠ ♦ ♥ ♣`:

```
CardsEnum.values foreach println
```